# Como hacer un formulario que tome datos por defecto en Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo una app donde un Usuario se puede matricular a unos cursos, con estos modelos: Usuario, Curso y Matricula.

Estos son los modelos:

```
class Alumno(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField('Nombres', max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('Apellido Paterno', max_length=30, blank=True)


class Curso(model.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField('Nombres', max_length=30, blank=True)
    fecha_inicio = models.DateField('Fecha de Inicio', null=True, blank=True)

class Matricula(models.Model):
    alumno = models.ForeignKey(Alumno, default='')
    curso = models.ForeignKey(Curso, default='')
    costo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    anotaciones = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    matriculado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

El modelo Alumno es un modelo AbstractUser por lo que el login y la autenticacion de usuario esta configurada para ser con ese modelo.
tengo una Vista de un DetailView de un curso y en esa vista quiero tener un boton que diga Matricularse y tome los id del curso actual y del usuario que debe estar logueado y los ingrese al modelo Matricula.

No se como tomar esos valores que se encuentran actualmente en la vista DetailView del Curso (user.id y curso.id) que son primordiales para el Modelo Matricula.
Esta es mi view.py:

```
class CursoDetail(DetailView):
    model = Curso
    template_name = 'home/curso.html'
```

Y esta es mi url.py

```
url(r'^curso_detail/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        CursoDetail.as_view(), name='curso_detail'),
```

Intenté hacerlo con un CreateView pero se muestran todos los usuarios y cursos en un form select, y no deberian mostrarse todos los Alumnos.

```
class Matricularse(CreateView):
    model = Matricula
    fields = ('alumno', 'curso',)
    template_name = 'intranet/matricularse.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('curso:intranet_list')
```

[image: Esta sería la forma de la vista con CreateView]

Comment: ¿Quieres recuperar esos datos en el `template`?

Comment: Quiero que en el template DetailView de Curso, donde se encuentra el objeto Curso y el Alumno, tome esos dos datos(Curso.id y Alumno.id) y los ponga en un nuevo Objeto de Matricula. Sin tener que entrar a un CreateView de Matricula; que el alumno no tenga que escojer el curso ni el alumno ya que esos datos ya se encuentran en la DetailView de un determinado Curso.

Comment: OK, pero a que instancia del modelo Alumno?

Comment: Si te fijas el modelo alumno es un AstractUser, por ejemplo si se hace un request.user se esta accediendo a una instancia del modelo user que es a fin de cuentas el modelo Alumno por lo que, en si se tomaría el id de la instancia del user y la del curso. Si me explico? (el auth.user por defecto de django lo configure con AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.Alumno' en settings.py, para que se use ese modelo para la autenticacion)

Comment: OK, ya edite mi respuesta checa la solución

Comment: Comenta si tienes problemas con el codigo.

Comment: Me puse a investigar mas sobre `AbstracUser` y me di cuenta de un error en mi código, lo acabo de corregir. por se acaso no te funcionaba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Según la [documentacion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) de `Django` de la vista `DetailView`:
>   Mientras se está ejecutando esta vista, `self.object` contendrá el objeto
>   sobre el que opera la vista.

Así que desde cualquier método que contenga la vista `DetailView` podrás acceder al objeto, a excepción del método `get_object`, ya que `self.object` se define a partir del resultado de `self.get_object()` por lo que no tiene sentido acceder a `self.object` dentro de `self.get_object()`, porque no existe.

Para tener acceso al `id` o al `pk` del objeto, seria de la siguiente manera en la vista:

```
self.object.pk
self.object.id
```

En dado caso que quieras acceder a esos datos desde el `template` lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
{{ object.pk }}
{{ object.id }}
{{ foo.pk }}
{{ foo.id }}
```

El nombre por defecto del objeto que se pasa al `template` es `object` o el nombre del modelo en minúsculas, de las dos maneras funcionan exactamente igual.

---

Para saber el usuario que inicio sesión, tendrías que hacerlo desde el método `dispatch` de la vista, sobrescribir el método, así:

```
class CursoDetail(DetailView):
    model = Curso
    template_name = 'home/curso.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Imprimimos el usuario que inicio sesión 
        print(request.user)

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

En cuanto a la vista `CreateView` crea un formulario personalizado y has que la vista se engarce de instanciarla, o crea el `form` con HTML en bruto.

Para indicarle que se engarce de instanciar el formulario personalizado, importa el formulario e indícalo en el atributo `form_class`, de la vista.

De la siguiente manera:

```
from .forms import MyForm

class Matricularse(CreateView):
    model = Matricula
    form_class = MyForm
    fields = ('alumno', 'curso',)
    template_name = 'intranet/matricularse.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('curso:intranet_list')
```

---

**Actualización:**

De acuerdo a tu comentario:

> Quiero que en el `template DetailView` de Curso, donde se encuentra el
>   objeto Curso y el Alumno, tome esos dos datos(`Curso.id` y `Alumno.id`) y
>   los ponga en un nuevo Objeto de Matricula. Sin tener que entrar a un
>   CreateView de Matricula; que el alumno no tenga que escojer el curso
>   ni el alumno ya que esos datos ya se encuentran en la DetailView de un
>   determinado Curso

Bueno primero un aviso, estas equivocado al momento de decir que el objeto Alumno se encuentra en la vista `DetailView` ya que la vista esta gestionando el modelo `Curso` no el modelo `Alumno`.

Volviendo al tema, para hacerlo, podrías hacerlo en la vista, no es necesario hacerlo en el `template` a menos que el usuario no vaya a interactuar con los datos.

En mi opinión seria mas limpio hacerlo en una vista basada en función, para mayor legibilidad del código, ya que en la vista basada en clase seria mas complicado y habría mucho mas código.

Aquí el código:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .models import Curso, Alumno, Matricula

def curso_detail(request, pk):
    # Obtenemos las instancias
    curso = get_object_or_404(Curso, pk = pk)
    alumno = get_object_or_404(Alumno, username = request.user)

    # Creamos una instancia del modelo Matricula
    # Ahi asigna los valores que tu quieras a los demas campos 
    Matricula.objects.create(alumno = alumno, curso = curso, costo = 100, matriculado = True)

    # Aqui tu te encargas si quieres renderisar un template o redireccionar a una url.
    return render(request, 'MyApp/example.html')
```

Recuerda tener bien configurado tus `urls` y pasar el parámetro `pk` a la vista.

Comment: Si funcionó, aunque los parámetros que usé fueron (self, pk, id), para enviar por ahi los id de curso y alumno, ya que me salia un error con el request. Gracias!

Comment: Mmmm, tuve un error ahora que me doy cuenta, me olvide de quitarle el `self` a la vista, quita el `self` de la vista, y capas eso era lo que causaba el error. Los parametros de la vista debe ser asi: `(request, pk)`  y el id, si es que quieres. Porcierto no es nesesario pasarle el id a la vista, porque el id y el pk son el mismo, un identificador unico.

Comment: Recuerda aceptar mi respuesta si es que ha resuelto tu problema o duda.