# Como actualizo la base de datos o modelo de Django con resultados de una operación en js?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

La operación matemática, la estoy haciendo en el front con JS, pero a la hora de querer, que ese resultado, se actualice en la base de datos, no sé, como hacer, alguna sugerencia por favor?

Archivo HTML:

```
{% extends "plantillas/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% now "Y-m-d H:i:s" %} <br>
{{ user.Peti}}
{{ user.numero_empleado}}
<script src="{% static 'js/int.js'%}"></script>

<div><form method="POST" id="demo">

{% csrf_token %}
<h6>Tipo de peticion:{{form.petit}}</h6>

<h6>Razon:{{form.razon}}</h6>

<h6>{{form.solicitudes_id}}</h6>
<h6>Fecha inicio:{{form.periodo_init}}</h6>
<h6>Fecha fin:{{form.periodo_fin}}</h6>
<h6>Introduzca dias a tomar<input id="dias" type="number" name="dias_adicion"></h6>
<h6>Introduzca horas a tomar<input id="horas" type="number" name="horas_adicion"></h6>
<input type="hidden" id="const_dias" name="d_pendientes" value="{{ user.d_pendientes }}">

<button type="submit" class="boton" onclick="calculo(); ">Guardar</button>

</div></form></span>


{% endblock %}
```

Y este es el `views.py` con la siguiente función:

```
def solit(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    form = addiForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect ('index')
    else:
        form = addiForm()
    return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form},args)
```

Y este es el modelo a donde quiero sumar 1 campo distinto de cada modelo (`models.py`):

```
class LocalUsers(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    usuario = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    apellido = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    numero_empleado = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    area = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    f_nac = models.DateField(max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    d_pendientes = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    h_pendientes = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class Peticion(models.Model):
    solit_choices = (
        ('Adicionar','Adicionar'),
    )
    solicitudes_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(LocalUsers, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    dias_adicion = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)
    horas_adicion = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'usuario'
```

Como se realizaría la suma u otra operación aritmética dado estos modelos en el `view`, es que no entiendo bien como seria, he intentado de muchas maneras y formas, pero aun no la capto, ayuda por favor.

El modelo `Peticion` lo renderizo en un form los campos a sumar de ese modelo seria el `d_pendientes + dias_adicion y h_pendientes + horas_adicion`, el resultado, quedaría en `d_pendientes` por que quiero que quede en el modelo `User` personalizado, algo como esto:

```
d_pendientes += dias_adicion y h_pendientes += horas_adicion
```

En el front intente con JavaScript, pero a la hora de guardar el dato resultando, no lo guarda, pensé guardarlo con AJAX, pero aun así tampoco me sirve o estoy haciendo algo mas, pero de la forma como lo consulto, mediante esta pregunta, es haciendo la operación en el view. Agradecería sus comentarios.

```
int.js 

function calculo()

{

    var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById('dias').value);
    var horas = parseFloat(document.getElementById('horas').value);
    var dias_base  = parseInt(document.getElementById('const_dias').value);
    var horas_base  = parseFloat(document.getElementById('const_horas').value);

    dias_base -= dias;
    horas_base -= horas;

    alert(dias_base);
    alert(horas_base);
} console.log(calculo);
```

Comment: Podrías hacer la operación simplemente en la vista, y así no te complicas mucho.

Comment: Como se hace la operación en la vista? o tienes alguna pagina o tutorial, donde muestren un ejemplo asi? @JulioCesar

Comment: Al momento de recibir los datos por POST, obtenlos de la siguiente manera: `request.POST.get('field')`,así obtén los campos que necesites y te encargas de hacer la operación matemática en la vista, una ves termines de hacerlo guardas los datos en la db.

Comment: @JulioCesar gracias por tu respuesta, pero como soy medio roockie, un ejemplo mas claro de la funcion o clase en el view con una suma de esa manera, por que seria la suma de 2 campos de diferentes modelos, gracias!!

Comment: OK, no te entendí en esta parte: "`un ejemplo mas claro de la función o clase en el view con una suma de esa manera, por que seria la suma de 2 campos de diferentes modelos`". A que te refieres?

Comment: @JulioCesar actualice la pregunta, con los datos del models.py y el view.py Accedo al model "peticion" a traves de un form, los datos de dias_adicion y horas_adicion, se le sumarian al modelo userPersonalizado de Django, como lo harias en el view? gracias de antemano

Comment: Explícame bien como es la operación y a que campo del modelo `userPersonalizado ` se  le tiene que sumar, para así ayudarte.

Comment: Listo, en el penultimo párrafo esta la información gracias!! <3

Comment: OK, estas adjuntando todo el código del modelo `LocalUsers`? Falta especificar el `USERNAME_FIELD` lo cual dará error si no se especifica, y otras cosas mas por especificar.

Comment: @JulioCesar si man, es solo un borrador para saber como se hace la operación en el view, agregue el USERNAME_FIELD y el archivo int.js, donde actualmente hago la operacion, per sin llegar a la BD. Tendrías que autorizar el modelo en el setting. AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'urapp.modeloPerzonalizado'

Comment: Mmmm ok, osea aun no haces las migraciones ni nada, verdad?

Comment: Man es obvio todo el proceso de makemigration y migrate, queda sobre entendido si yo necesito logearme, antes de hacer todo loq ue te menciono. Creo, que no te estoy entendiendo, que mas necesitas? o que necesitas que haga, para darme a entender mejor?

Comment: OK ya publique mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 0):

Intentare dar una respuesta a tu problema. Daremos por hecho que el modelo `LocalUsers` ya esta configurado correctamente, etc.

Para hacer los siguiente:

> El modelo `Peticion` lo renderizo en un  `form` los campos a sumar de ese
>   modelo seria el `d_pendientes` + `dias_adicion` y `h_pendientes` +
>   `horas_adicion`, el resultado, quedaría en `d_pendientes` por que quiero
>   que quede en el modelo userpersonalizado, algo como esto: `d_pendientes`
>   += `dias_adicion` y `h_pendientes` += `horas_adicion`

Seria de la siguiente manera en la vista:

```
from .models import LocalUsers

def solit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = addiForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Obtenemos la instancia
            user = LocalUsers.objects.get(...)
            # Modificamos la instancia
            user.d_pendientes += request.POST.get('dias_adicion')
            user.h_pendientes += request.POST.get('horas_adicion')

            user.save()
            form.save()

        return redirect(reverse('index'))

    form = addiForm()
    return render(request, 'plantillas/adicionar.html', {'form':form})
```

Debido a que no se mucho sobre el tema de `AbstractBaseUser` no sabría decirte como se debe recuperar la instancia ya que varia mucho dependiendo la estructura del `AbstractBaseUser`.

Por ultimo no es necesario pasar al contexto del `template` el usuario loggeado, ya viene por defecto inyectado en el contexto global.

Comment: Digamos, que no lo hago con AbstractBaseUser y lo hago de otra forma, que tu si sepas o te sea mas comoda de hacer? como lo harias? Asi sea con Abstrac u otro estructura de user, que te sea mas comoda. De veras muchas gracias!!. En la linea "user = LocalUsers.objects.get(....), que va alli?

Comment: Entonces seria así: `User.objects.get(pk = request.user.pk)`, lógicamente tienes que importar el modelo `User`.

Comment: Pero sin personalizar el usuario lo cual no tendría sentido agregar dichos campos o modificaros, pero también serviría con un `AbstractUser`, solo habria que remplazar el `User` por el `AbstractUser`.

Comment: Man, creo que con tu ayuda, que agradezco mucho, estoy cerca de lograrlo hehehe, te dare todos los likes posibles hahaha, no se actualiza el valor, pero en el server me imprime algo asi: [17/Jul/2019 07:51:27] "GET /solit/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=qhU6yd0nMRoNpBXwK0a8T5p8I4S9TU47r6mm9vY0DW3LEGCVTEdmhXnnApxR8TDS&petit=Adicionar&razon=jonathan+adamson&periodo_init=2019-05-31&periodo_fin=2019-06-01&dias_adicion=2&horas_adicion=2&d_pendientes=3&h_pendientes=3.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 3238. Cambio la estructura a Abstract? para hacerlo mas sencillo? O estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Seria mas sencillo hacerlo por Abstract, y parece ser que la razon por la cual no se guardan los datos es por que envias los datos por GET, debes enviarlos por POST.

Comment: Mira esta pregunta, tiene un problema mas o menos similar al tuyo, así tendrás una referencia mas clara de como solucionar tu problema: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275006/como-hacer-un-formulario-que-tome-datos-por-defecto-en-django/275271

Comment: En este caso me parece mas que suficiente hacerlo con el `AbstractUser`, no veo necesario hacerlo con un `AbstractBaseUser` ya que estas construyendo un modelo de usuario desde cero y no lo veo necesario para tu caso.